# Chrome resource loading behaviour

Tags: google-chrome

Today I ran into rather a strange behaviour of Chrome. I was playing with [PerformanceObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PerformanceObserver/PerformanceObserver) and found out that when you add two stylesheets with the same URL to the DOM very quickly then chrome fires only one request which obviously makes sense as it saves network load.

```js
const testCase = async () => {
    let numberOfRecords = 0
    const observer = new PerformanceObserver((entryList) => {
        const performanceEntries = entryList.getEntries()
        numberOfRecords += performanceEntries.length
    })

    observer.observe({ entryTypes: ['resource'] })

    // Test: Only one performance record is created because links are added at the same time
    // and chrome detects duplicate request
    const linkElement1 = document.createElement('link')
    linkElement1.rel = 'stylesheet'
    linkElement1.href = 'https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css'
    document.head.appendChild(linkElement1)

    const linkElement2 = document.createElement('link')
    linkElement2.rel = 'stylesheet'
    linkElement2.href = 'https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css'
    document.head.appendChild(linkElement2)

    // wait a little bit so performance observer callback is called
    await new Promise((resolve) => {
        setTimeout(() => resolve(), 1000)
    })
    console.assert(numberOfRecords === 1, 'Test')
    console.log('Test finished')
}

testCase()
```

When sleep time is added between adding link nodes to DOM then chrome fires two requests (the second one is taken from cache)

```js
const testCase = async () => {
    let numberOfRecords = 0
    const observer = new PerformanceObserver((entryList) => {
        const performanceEntries = entryList.getEntries()
        numberOfRecords += performanceEntries.length
    })

    observer.observe({ entryTypes: ['resource'] })

    // Test: Only one performance record is created because links are added at the same time
    // and chrome detects duplicate request
    const linkElement1 = document.createElement('link')
    linkElement1.rel = 'stylesheet'
    linkElement1.href = 'https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css'
    document.head.appendChild(linkElement1)

    // wait here so chrome triggers two requests
    await new Promise((resolve) => {
        setTimeout(() => resolve(), 1000)
    })

    const linkElement2 = document.createElement('link')
    linkElement2.rel = 'stylesheet'
    linkElement2.href = 'https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css'
    document.head.appendChild(linkElement2)

    // wait a little bit so performance observer callback is called
    await new Promise((resolve) => {
        setTimeout(() => resolve(), 1000)
    })
    console.assert(numberOfRecords === 2, 'Test')
    console.log('Test finished')
}

testCase()
```

However when I run this second code via automated test (webdriver.io) or I try it on cloud service like Browserstack/Lambdatest (the same browser version, OS version) it fails as it triggers only one request. So I wonder what's the difference?

To see it by yourself you can open some [empty page](http://www.blankwebsite.com/) (it's quite important that page is empty and doesn't contain any background requests) and copy the code examples to console.

Comment: When doing web development via a local server, I've noticed that hitting cmd+R seems to reload most resources regardless of their cache lifetime, but has inconsistent results regarding stylesheets (in more than one browser).  My vague impression is that browsers use their own heuristics to decide when to reload something – I don't know what or why, but it does seem to be different for stylesheets specifically.

Answer (score 1):

I just wonder whether you disabled the cache for the automation tests. In Chrome, apparently if you didn't tick "Disable cache", then you second test should fail.